# Missing right parenthesis while querying in oracle db

Tags: oracle

I am using below query :

```
Select identifier 
from batch_instance 
where batch_class_id IN ( Select id 
                          from batch_class  
                          where ROWNUM <2 AND 
                          batch_class_name='abc' 
                          ORDER BY creation_date DESC);
```

PFB error :

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: You can't have an `order by` in a subquery - just remove that. ([Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21859866/266304), though not the clearest question; I'll keep looking...)

Comment: Also where will be applied before order by so subquery is not returning newest id for 'abc'

Comment: The construct is wrong anyway if you're trying to decide which two rows in batch_class are used. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28451660/266304) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I looked at that other answer... it just occurs to me I could do some testing on this, but in my mind using `keep (dense_rank first/last)` should be preferred in such situations. Finding first/last should take at most O(n) time (O(log n) if `creation_date` is indexed), while ordering the whole set just to pick the first or last row is O(n log n) time. Right?

Comment: @mathguy - except Oracle uses stop count when it notices this sort of thing, so if it's indexed I wouldn't expect it to actually order everything. But yes, using `keep` is neater and clearer and may be more (or at least *as*) efficient - I don't think I've compared them properly in this situation either. You could maybe join and not use a subquery at all, with `max(identifier) keep...` but that would need further investigation too.

Comment: @AlexPoople : Thanks removing order by from subquery solved issue.Just to add,above query shared by me works fine on mysql.Correct query for oracle : Select identifier from batch_instance where batch_class_id IN(Select id from batch_class  where ROWNUM =1 AND batch_class_name='abc' )ORDER BY creation_date DESC;

Answer (score 1):

The subquery (assuming it's fixed) will return one row only. So it returns only one `id`. In that case, there is no point in using an `IN` condition, an "equal" comparison will have the same effect.

To select the most recent `id` associated with the name `'abc'`, you can use `keep (dense_rank last)` so it's still all done in a single subquery - you won't need nested subqueries. Something like:

```
select identifier
from   batch_instance
where  batch_class_id = ( select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by creation_date)
                          from   batch_class
                          where  batch_class_name =    'abc'
                        )
;
```